# Do I need to remove "Ubuntu" from the boot menu after removing dual boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I've recently decided to remove the dual boot on my laptop. Everything's working fine at the moment, my computer boots into windows 10 on startup (as intended), but Ubuntu is still listed in the boot menu. I've tried to remove it but nothing I've tried has worked.

Do I need to remove it? I don't intend to dual boot on this laptop again, so I'm not sure if just leaving it there would cause any problems.

Also, there's a BIOS update available, will having this ubuntu listing interfere with that?

My computer is using uefi.

Answer (score 2):

Although you have deleted Ubuntu partitions like **/** , **/boot** , **/home**,  the ubuntu boot loader is still in the EFI partition.
If your PC is booting into grub command line then change your default bootloader to windows boot manager

**Run using CMD**

`bootrec /fixmbr`
`bootsect /nt60`

Now, your PC will boot into windows 10 by default. But ubuntu boot files are still in EFI partition. These files will not interfere with your windows 10 boot loader.
But I suggest you to remove them as Ubuntu is not present and they are auto installed on any new os installation.

**This answer borrowed verbatim from [here](http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/))**

1. Run a `cmd.exe` process with administrator privileges
2. Run `diskpart`
3. Type: `list disk` then `sel disk X` where X is the drive your boot files reside on
4. Type `list vol` to see all partitions (volumes) on the disk (the EFI volume will be formatted in FAT, others will be NTFS)
5. Select the EFI volume by typing: `sel vol Y` where Y is the `SYSTEM` volume (this is almost always the EFI partition)
6. For convenience, assign a drive letter by typing: `assign letter=Z:` where Z is a free (unused) drive letter
7. Type `exit` to leave disk part
8. While still in the `cmd` prompt, type: `Z:` and hit enter, where Z was the drive letter you just created.
9. Type `dir` to list directories on this mounted EFI partition
10. If you are in the right place, you should see a directory called `EFI`
11. Type `cd EFI` and then `dir` to list the child directories inside `EFI`
12. Type `rmdir /S ubuntu` to delete the ubuntu boot directory