# Why ubuntu is appearing in boot menu even i removed from dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

## System

Laptop: Lenovo IdeaPad 330 15AST
Processor: AMD A6 
Platform: windows 10 
I had installed in the dual boot along with windows 10. Now, i want to install `parrot os` in the dual boot along with windows 10. In order to do that, i deleted the partition where i had installed `ubuntu`. After that, i removed ubuntu from the `grub boot menu` using the following methods.

[Do I need to remove "Ubuntu" from the boot menu after removing dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204518/do-i-need-to-remove-ubuntu-from-the-boot-menu-after-removing-dual-boot)

After this, i was expecting that it should be removed from the grub boot menu. Again i opened boot menu and i got this..
[image]

Again when i follow the same approach to see if there is ubuntu in the grub menu or not.
Then i got this. 
[image]
You can see,there is no option for ubuntu. 
 You can see, still there is ubuntu in boot menu. [image]

Comment: I think what you are worried about here are artifacts left behind in your firmware. Your motherboard manual may tell you how to reset this. They shouldn't do any harm.

Comment: How do i fix this issue.

Comment: I don't have much experience in computer work.

Comment: Two simple things. One, try focusing on "5. Ubuntu" as per your 3rd picture and press delete. In some UEFI/BIOS this will remove the entry. Two, add the make and model of your computer to the question.

Comment: I did the changes as you said.

Answer (score -1):

As `PonJar said`, i pressed the delete button in the first picture instead of 2nd picture. Then a cross sign appears on the left side on `ubuntu`.Then i restarted and everything works.